# Два разных домен контроллера в одной сети?

Tags: сервер, controller, active-directory

Есть **старый** контроллер домена office.**local**, можно ли создать в одной и той же сети новый контроллер домена например newoffice.**local**, который так же заканчивается на **.local**?
Никаких доверительных отношений между ними ни будет.
Просто заново хочу создать **новый домен** с службами и  создать всех новых пользователей и перевести их на новый домен, а **старый изъять**. 
Какие последствия?
Варианты решение? 
Спасибо